# How to override a property set in an id (CSS)

Tags: css

Suppose the following code:

```html
<div id="body" class='bodyLogin'>
```

```css
#body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

I would like to override the background colour through the class attribute, like this:

```
#body .bodyLogin {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

but this doesn't work.

Similarly:

```
.bodyLogin  {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

doesn't work due to CSS hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space between your two selectors is meaningful. In fact it is a *selector*: the [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#descendant-selectors). It means you select all of class `bodyLogin` *descendant* of an element with id `body`.

Get rid of the space and you select elements that are both `#body` *and* `.bodyLogin`:

```css
#body {
    background-color: red;
}

#body.bodyLogin {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="body" class='bodyLogin'>Test</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.